# Route All traffic through a VM in VMWorkstation

Tags: networking, vmware, benchmarking, reverse-proxy

I'm testing an Nginx reverse proxy (stress test) on my own computer using VMWorkstation, but i don't know how to route all traffic through Nginx .

Traffic must go from My Computer > Nginx > Webserver 1 or 2 depending on the reverse proxy settings.

[image]

i am stuck in the routing part , How can i accomplish this ?

Comment: I think if you have no other network cards enabled then you should be able to open the properties of the Host adapter and set the gateway there to 192.168.1.20

Comment: i Will try to set Default Gateway As .20 to all and see what it gives , but i think perhaps i will try to Change the network adresses inside to another subnet , because by default all trafic goes from the Vmware Gateway to the web servers when i access a web page from my pc